# Linux Mint 20 Without a Dedicated Graphics Card

Tags: linux-mint, intel-graphics

I plan to get rid of Windows on my wife's laptop and install Mint 20 Cinnamon edition on it. The laptop is a bit old. So I just wanted to know, does it work nicely of an Intel graphics? I read a lot about it being pretty and all. And thought, pretty would mean it might need a dedicated GPU. The processor is Core i3. From what I know it is two generations older than the current ones on the market. I have to look at the specs in detail. Any advice on this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And thought, pretty would mean it might need a dedicated GPU.

For games or CAD/3D modelling maybe. For normal day to day tasks - hardly required.

> So I just wanted to know, does it work nicely of an Intel graphics?

Linux drivers for Intel graphics are considered top notch. Multiple people around me, me including, have laptops with integrated Intel graphics and I don't remember having any serious issues in a long time.

Comment: I installed Mint. And it seems to be handling stuff pretty well. Yes its no Ferrari. But I don't expect it to be. But is pretty zippy. Don't see any graphics/drivers issue now.. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Drivers for intel video is in kernel, must be ok.

But let me raise one general problem I am facing when installing Linux on a 'old' PC:  After a while, users compare with *newest*, more powerfull friend's machine, and found that 'Linux is slow', but naturally in fact meaning 'hardware is slow' .
Probably you can explain that to your wife, but maybe it is a good moment to get a -eventually second hand- more powerfull CPU.
(Sorry if mistakes, my primary language is french)

Comment: Last 10 years (*maybe more)* general purpose intel cards are great even for medium performances on 3D.  I strongly agree.

Comment: Generally what I have seen, Linux machines handle older hardware faaar better than Windows. Can't say about MACs. Don't have experience about them.